# how to used .grid() to push my gui to the left

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

for a school project i need to make a Tkinter Gui that controls certain leds and etc.

[i want to make it as good as possible but right now evrything is kinda pushed to the left, could anyone help me to place it in the middle?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEktT.png)

this is a part of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL as p
import PIL.ImageTk as ptk
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

#variabelen voor relais window
global ledstate1 #er wordt gewerkt met het woord ledstate omdat dit al gebruikt werkt in de testfase, geen andere redenen
ledstate1 = 0
global ledstate2
ledstate2 = 0
global ledstate3
ledstate3 = 0
global ledstate4
ledstate4 = 0
global ledstate5
ledstate5 = 0
global ledstate6
ledstate6 = 0
global ledstate7
ledstate7 = 0
global ledstate8
ledstate8 = 0
global ledstate9
ledstate9 = 0

DEVICE = 0x20 #Device address (A0-A2)
IODIRA = 0x00 #pin direction register
OLATA  = 0x14 #register for outputs
GPIOA  = 0x12 #register for inputs

#set all GPA pins as outputs by setting
#all bits of IODIRA register to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,IODIRA,0x00)

#set output all 7 output bits to 0
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,0)

mainwindow=Tk()

mainframe=Frame(mainwindow,bg='linen')
mainframe.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
mainwindow.geometry('800x480')
mainwindow.resizable(False,False)
mainwindow.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

#alle frames aanmaken voor hoofdscherm
menu=Frame(mainframe,bg='linen',highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
beveiliging=Frame(mainframe,bg='linen',highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
metingen=Frame(mainframe,bg='linen',highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=2)
#alle frames op het scherm zetten
menu.pack(side='top',fill='x')
beveiliging.pack(side='top',fill='x')
metingen.pack(side='top',fill='x')

# Keep track of the button state on/off


#open commands voor de extra windows
def open_relais():
    #window aanmaken
    relais = Toplevel(bg='linen')
    relais.title('first window')
    relais.geometry('800x480')
    relais.resizable(False,False)
    relais.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    #labels onderdelen aanmaken
    #welk onderdeel
    Label14=Label(relais, text='3 Fasen',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    Label15=Label(relais, text='1 Fase + aarding',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    Label16=Label(relais, text='1 Fase geïsoleerd',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)

    Label14.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
    Label15.grid(column=1,row=2,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
    Label16.grid(column=1,row=4,padx=20,pady=15,sticky='new')
    
    #knop 1 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F)   ## Stop_bus betekent stopcontact + bus
    Stop_bus_3F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact + Bussen',command=lambda: Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_bus_3F.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate1 else "red")
    #knop 2 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F)
    Stop_3F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact',command=lambda: Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_3F.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate2 else "red")
    #knop 3 aanmaken, werkt samen met Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F)
    Bus_3F = Button(relais,text='Bussen',command=lambda: Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Bus_3F.grid(column=2,row=1,padx=20,pady=12)
    Bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate3 else "red")
    
    #knop 4 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_bus_1F_1(Stop_bus_1F)
    Stop_bus_1F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact + Bussen',command=lambda: Stop_bus_1F_1(Stop_bus_1F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_bus_1F.grid(column=1,row=3,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_bus_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate4 else "red")
    #knop 5 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_1F_1(Stop_1F)
    Stop_1F = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact',command=lambda: Stop_1F_1(Stop_1F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_1F.grid(column=0,row=3,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate5 else "red")
    #knop 6 aanmaken, werkt samen met Bus_1F_1(Bus_1F)
    Bus_1F = Button(relais,text='Bussen',command=lambda: Bus_1F_1(Bus_1F),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Bus_1F.grid(column=2,row=3,padx=20,pady=12)
    Bus_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate6 else "red")

    #knop 7 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_bus_1FX_1(Stop_bus_1FX)     'X' staat voor geïsoleerd
    Stop_bus_1FX = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact + Bussen',command=lambda: Stop_bus_1FX_1(Stop_bus_1FX),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_bus_1FX.grid(column=1,row=5,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_bus_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate7 else "red")
    #knop 8 aanmaken, werkt samen met Stop_1FX_1(Stop_1FX)
    Stop_1FX = Button(relais,text='Stopcontact',command=lambda: Stop_1FX_1(Stop_1FX),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Stop_1FX.grid(column=0,row=5,padx=20,pady=12)
    Stop_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate8 else "red")
    #knop 9 aanmaken, werkt samen met Bus_1FX_1(Bus_1FX)
    Bus_1FX= Button(relais,text='Bussen',command=lambda: Bus_1FX_1(Bus_1FX),fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
    Bus_1FX.grid(column=2,row=5,padx=20,pady=12)
    Bus_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate9 else "red")
    
    #close button aanmaken
    close_button = Button(relais, text='close window', command=relais.destroy).grid(column=1,row=6,padx=20,pady=15)
def open_2():
    open_2 = Toplevel()
    open_2.title('second window')
    open_2.geometry('800x480')
    close_button = Button(open_2, text='close window', command=open_2.destroy).pack()
def open_3():
    open_3 = Toplevel()
    open_3.title('third window')
    open_3.geometry('800x480')
    close_button = Button(open_3, text='close window', command=open_3.destroy).pack()     
def open_4():
    open_4 = Toplevel()
    open_4.title('fourth window')
    open_4.geometry('800x480')
    close_button = Button(open_4, text='close window', command=open_4.destroy).pack()

#commands voor onderdelen aan/uit
# 3FASE
def Stop_bus_3F_1(Stop_bus_3F):
    if ledstate2 == 0:                   #door deze lijnen kan er maar 1 van de drie onderdelen aangeschakeld worden
        if ledstate3 == 0:               # er moet dus gekozen worden tussen stopcontact + bus, bussen of stopcontact
            global ledstate1
            ledstate1 = 1 - ledstate1
            print(ledstate1)
            Stop_bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate1 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,ledstate1)
def Stop_3F_1(Stop_3F):
    if ledstate1 == 0:
        if ledstate3 == 0:
            global ledstate2
            ledstate2 = 1 - ledstate2
            if ledstate2 == 1:           #alpha is een variable die ervoor zorgt dat we kunnen schrijven naar de 2e uitgang
                alpha = 2                #want ledstate2 is = 0 of 1
            else:
                alpha = 0
            print(alpha)
            Stop_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate2 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,alpha)
def Bus_3F_1(Bus_3F):
    if ledstate1 == 0:
        if ledstate2 == 0:
            global ledstate3
            ledstate3 = 1 - ledstate3
            if ledstate3 == 1:           #beta is een variable die ervoor zorgt dat we kunnen schrijven naar de 3e uitgang
                beta = 4                 #want ledstate3 is = 0 of 1   ## beta moet 4 zijn om de 3e uitgang te activeren
            else:
                beta = 0
            print(beta)
            Bus_3F.config(bg="green" if ledstate3 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,beta)
# 1FASE
def Stop_bus_1F_1(Stop_bus_1F):
    if ledstate5 == 0:
        if ledstate6 == 0:
            global ledstate4
            ledstate4 = 1 - ledstate4
            if ledstate4 == 1:          
                gamma = 8              
            else:                                                           
                gamma = 0
            print(gamma)
            Stop_bus_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate4 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,gamma)
def Stop_1F_1(Stop_1F):
    if ledstate4 == 0:
        if ledstate6 == 0:
            global ledstate5
            ledstate5 = 1 - ledstate5
            if ledstate5 == 1:          
                delta = 3               #delta MOET 16 ZIJN OM DE 4E UITGANG TE ACTIVEREN MAAR OM TE TESTEN DOEN WE 3
            else:                                                            # ik heb maar een paar leds om te testen
                delta = 0
            print(delta)
            Stop_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate5 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,delta)
def Bus_1F_1(Bus_1F):
    if ledstate4 == 0:
        if ledstate5 == 0:
            global ledstate6
            ledstate6 = 1 - ledstate6
            if ledstate6 == 1:          
                epsilon = 5               #epsilon MOET 32 ZIJN OM DE 4E UITGANG TE ACTIVEREN MAAR OM TE TESTEN DOEN WE 5
            else:
                epsilon = 0
            print(epsilon)
            Bus_1F.config(bg="green" if ledstate6 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,epsilon)
#geisoleerd
def Stop_bus_1FX_1(Stop_bus_1FX):
    if ledstate8 == 0:
        if ledstate9 == 0:
            global ledstate7
            ledstate7 = 1 - ledstate7
            if ledstate7 == 1:          
                wau = 7                   #wau MOET 64 ZIJN OM DE 4E UITGANG TE ACTIVEREN MAAR OM TE TESTEN DOEN WE 7
            else:                                                           
                wau = 0
            print(wau)
            Stop_bus_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate7 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,wau)
def Stop_1FX_1(Stop_1FX):
    if ledstate7 == 0:
        if ledstate9 == 0:
            global ledstate8
            ledstate8 = 1 - ledstate8
            if ledstate8 == 1:          
                zeta = 9               #zeta MOET 128 ZIJN OM DE 4E UITGANG TE ACTIVEREN MAAR OM TE TESTEN DOEN WE 9
            else:                                                            
                zeta = 0
            print(zeta)
            Stop_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate8 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,zeta)
def Bus_1FX_1(Bus_1FX):
    if ledstate7 == 0:
        if ledstate8 == 0:
            global ledstate9
            ledstate9 = 1 - ledstate9
            if ledstate9 == 1:          
                eta = 11               #eta MOET 256 ZIJN OM DE 4E UITGANG TE ACTIVEREN MAAR OM TE TESTEN DOEN WE 11
            else:
                eta = 0
            print(eta)
            Bus_1FX.config(bg="green" if ledstate9 else "red")
            bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE,OLATA,eta)



#inhoud menu frame
    #VTI="/home/pi/Documents/Scripts/VTI pic.jpg"
    #VTI1=p.Image.open(VTI)
    #VTI2=ptk.PhotoImage(VTI1)

    #Foto=Label(menu,image=VTI2)
    #Foto.pack()

#ZORG DAT DE TEKST OP DE KNOP 19-20 TEKENS LANG IS, zo ziet dit er beter uit op het scherm
button1=Button(menu,text='help me in here',command=open_relais,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
button1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=23,pady=15,sticky='nsew')



#afsluitknop
button4=Button(menu,text='     Afsluiten     ',command=mainwindow.destroy,bg='grey89',fg='black',padx=10,pady=10)
button4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=23,pady=15,sticky='nsew')
```

The problem is in the second window, if you click 'help me in here', where everything is kinda pushed left. i dont think this is a particulary hard problem to solve but i cant seem to find a solution

Comment: This is because those columns are very skinny. I recommend using place(x=10, y=10), or use \\n\n\n\n\n

Comment: Please reduce the example code to a minimum, such that it still reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in a frame and use `pack()` on the frame to put it on the top middle of the window:

```py
def open_relais():
    #window aanmaken
    # changed relais to win to reduce changes
    win = Toplevel(bg='linen')
    win.title('first window')
    #win.geometry('800x480')
    win.resizable(False,False)
    win.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

    # create a frame using relais as name
    relais = Frame(win)
    relais.pack() # put the frame at the top of the window

    #labels onderdelen aanmaken
    #welk onderdeel
    Label14=Label(relais, text='3 Fasen',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    label15=Label(relais, text='1 Fase + aarding',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)
    label16=Label(relais, text='1 Fase geïsoleerd',bg='white',fg='black',borderwidth=2,relief='solid',font=('Helvetica',19,'bold'),padx=12,pady=5)

    ...

    #close button aanmaken
    Button(relais, text='close window', command=win.destroy).grid(column=1,row=6,padx=20,pady=15)
```